# Devise registration routes do not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise

I'm currently working on implementing `devise` with the `devise-jwt` plugin on my Rails API app.
I've added the necessary configuration for devise but when it came to routes, registration routes don't seem to exist...

When I run `rails routes` I get this output:

```
     new_user_session GET    /login(.:format)                                                                         sessions#new
         user_session POST   /login(.:format)                                                                         sessions#create
 destroy_user_session DELETE /logout(.:format)
```

Here is what my `app/config/routes.rb` file looks like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users,
         path: '',
         path_names: {
           sign_in: 'login',
           sign_out: 'logout',
           registration: 'signup'
         },
         # i use my own custom controllers for this
         controllers: {
           sessions: 'sessions',
           registrations: 'registrations'
         }
end
```

I am overriding sessions/registrations, using my own like so:

### sessions controller

```
# app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb

class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  private

  def respond_with(resource, _opts = {})
    render json: resource
  end

  def response_to_on_destroy
    head :no_content
  end
end
```

### registration controller

```
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb

class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource.save
    render_resource(resource)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `:registerable` inside the User model.  I am not sure what your model looks like but in the group of Devise modules to include make sure `:registerable` is there.

```
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, <-- This one
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable
```